# Destructuring Ruby block arguments dynamically

Tags: ruby, arrays, block

A recent good [article](http://tony.pitluga.com/2011/08/08/destructuring-with-ruby.html) on ruby destructuring defines destructuring  as ability to bind a set of variables to a corresponding set of values anywhere that you can normally bind a value to a single variable, and gives an example of block destructuring

```
triples = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]

triples.each { |(first, second, third)| puts second } =>#[2, 5, 8]
```

In this case we have an idea of the number of elements in the main array and therefore when we provide the arguments first,second,third we can get the corresponding result. So what about if we had an array of arrays whose size is determined at run-time?

```
triples = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9],...,[]]
```

and we would want to get the elements of the first entry for each subarray?

```
triples.each { |(first, second, third,...,n)| puts first }
```

what is the best way to create the local variables `(first, second, third,...,n)` dynamically?

Comment: But why do you need to create the variables dynamically?

Comment: because i want to get the nth elements of each subarray. say the 20th for example

Comment: because I want to get the elements of the nth index for each subarray.  the elements for the 31st index of each subarray, given that the subarrays contain more than 31 elements.

Comment: If you don't destructure them, you'll get them as an array. I don't see a situation where it would make sense to have them destructured.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In your specific case, you'd use a splat to collect up everything but the first value:

```
triples.each { |first, *rest| puts first }
#-----------------------^splat
```

The `*rest` notation just collects everything that's left into an Array called `rest`.

In general, there's not much point to creating an arbitrary number of local variables (`second, third, ..., nth`) because you wouldn't be able to do anything with them; you could probably whip up a sick mess of evals but we already have a fine and functional Array class so why bother?

Comment: Say i want to get the elements of the nth index for each subarray?

Comment: @eastafri: Then you could `each {|x| ... }` and say `x[n-1]` or `rest[n-2]` if you have `|first, *rest|`. The `|k,v|` "destructuring" syntax is just a convenient shorthand to be used when you know how many elements you're working with and for things like `a, b = [11, 23]`, if you don't know how many elements you have then you use an array and ask it how big it is.

Answer (score 3):

if this is the array of arrays:

```
triples = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9],...,[]]
```

and we want to iterate over triples, then this will work because the inner arrays only have 3 elements each.

```
triples.each { |first, second, third| puts first }
```

Or, did you mean to type?

```
new_triples = [[1, 2, 3,...,n], [4, 5, 6,...,n], [7, 8, 9,...,n],...,[]]
```

in this case, I would use the suggestion of 'mu' above

```
new_triples.each { |first, *rest| puts first }
```

Hope I have captured your intent, sorry otherwise.